# Как мне сделать placeholder который будет изменяться при смене языка?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, placeholder

Я использую vue-i18n для того чтобы менять язык при сменен определенного select.
У меня есть отдельный компонент, где я как раз пишу логику для смены языка. Со статикой проблем нету, я передавал данные за место слов вот так **{{ $t("save_price") }}**, но мне нужно поменять Placeholder с русского на английский и наоборот при смене языка. Тут и есть проблема. Как мне это сделать? Вот компонент (1) где вся логика для языков:

```
import vCustomQa from "@/components/v-customQA.vue";

export default {
  en: {
    exit: 'Log out',
    user: 'User',
    price_values: 'What direction of price movement do you expect?',
    expected_price: 'Select your expected price range:',
    save_price: 'Do you want to hedge against the opposite direction of price movement?',
    yes: 'yes',
    no: 'no',
    recommended_price: 'Select recommended range:',
    futures: 'Do you want to get additional profit by selling futures?',
    selling_futures: 'Selling futures requires depositing margin into the account in an amount equal to the notional value of the futures',
    SEND: 'SEND ORDER',
    placeholder:'Choose the direction of travel',

  },
  ru: {
    exit: 'Выйти',
    user: 'Пользователь',
    price_values:'Ожидаемые значения цены',
    expected_price:'Выбрать рекомендуемый диапазон',
    save_price: 'Хотите ли застраховаться от противоположного направления движения цены?',
    yes: 'Да',
    no: 'Нет',
    recommended_price: 'Выбрать рекомендуемый диапазон',
    futures: 'Хотите ли получать дополнительную прибыль за счет продажи фьючерса?',
    selling_futures: 'Продажа фьючерса требует внесения на счет базового актива в количестве равном номиналу проданных фьючерсов',
    SEND: 'ОТПРАВИТЬ ЗАКАЗ',
    placeholder: 'Выберите напраление движения',
  },
  components: {
    vCustomQa,
  },
}
```

компонент (2), где нужно заменить placeholder при смене языка:

```
<vSelect
  v-model="selectedDirection"
  :placeholder="'Выберите напраление движения'"
  :options="directionOptions"
  class="select_change select-gradient"
  @input="setDirection"
>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<vSelect
 v-model="selectedDirection"
 v-bind:placeholder="$t('путь к плейсхолдеру')"
 :options="directionOptions"
 class="select_change select-gradient"
 @input="setDirection"
>
```